# How can i use my custom built javascript package with a UMD bundle within pure html or vanillajs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, umd, unpkg

I have built an NPM package called `atlas-pay-sdk` which is essentially a checkout gateway for a fintech. I was able to use this package with no issues in a React app by doing the normal import AtlasPay from `atlas-pay-sdk`.

Now, I'm building a Magento plugin that needs to utilize this package via a  tag and unpkg, but I'm unable to access the main function `AtlasPay`. So I created an HTML file and tried calling unpkg this way:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script async type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/atlas-pay-sdk@1.1.5/bundles/index.umd.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const atlasPay = AtlasPaySdk.AtlasPay;
      atlasPay.init({trxRef: 'your_trxRef'});
    </script>
    <button onclick="atlasPay.init()" class="test_btn">Init Payment</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. When I try accessing it via the window object in the browser console, I only see AtlasPaySdk, which is the package name, and it always returns AtlasPaySdk = {}.
Can someone please help me understand what I might be doing wrong?

I have also converted the package itself from functional to class based and again tried initializing it this way `const atlasPay = new AtlasPaySdk()` but still got the same issue

here is a link to the npm package itself incase someone is willing to give a try to this issue: [Atlas Pay SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/atlas-pay-sdk)